# Trying to link to a custom css file in a new folder

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, links, css

I'm trying to link to a custom css file in a new folder of a small plugin I'm trying to make. I can't seem to get it to work. This is the line I have

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' .  esc_url( plugins_url( 'public/css/front-end/uwc-tabs-style.css', __FILE__)) . '" >';
```

I've also tried the following but neither works.

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . plugins_url( 'public/css/front-end/uwc-tabs-style.css', __FILE__) . '" >';
```

As an edit. This is for an options result. eg. Select option 1 it returns the above stylesheet on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

I would use `wp_enqueue_style()` for this instead of echoing a `<link>`.

Comment: That's a much better way. I don't know why I didn't do it like that before The link worked, but the enqueuing will be much better all around.

Answer (score -1):

I worked it out. In case anyone else comes here looking for the answer here it is. I just had to add `dirname(__FILE__)` in place of `__FILE__`

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' .  esc_url( plugins_url( 'public/css/front-end/uwc-tabs-style.css', dirname(__FILE__))) . '" >';
```

Comment: better to use `wp_enqueue_style` for this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/